# DTM: capture form elements that have been changed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a requirement to capture into eVar a string of fields that have been changed when user updated their details.

I am using DTM and am thinking how to make it work.

Firstly I wrote this code and saved it as Data Element in the DTM:

```js
var oldMobileNo = document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value;
var oldAnotherNo = document.getElementById('additionalTelephoneNumber').value;
var oldEmail = document.getElementById('emailConfirmed').value;
document.forms['editContactVO'].onsubmit = function(){
  var newMobileNo = document.getElementById('mobileNumber').value;
  if(oldMobileNo != newMobileNo) {
    var MobileNo = "mobile number changed";
  }
  else {
    var MobileNo = "";
  }
  var newAnotherNo = document.getElementById('additionalTelephoneNumber').value;
  if(oldAnotherNo != newAnotherNo) {
    var AnotherNo = "additional number changed";
  }
  else {
    var AnotherNo = "";
  }
  var newEmail = document.getElementById('emailConfirmed').value;
  if(oldEmail != newEmail) {
    var Email = "email changed";
  }
  else {
    var Email = "";
  }
 return MobileNo;
 return AnotherNo;
 return Email; 
}

var Final = MobileNo + "," + AnotherNo + "," + Email;
return Final;
```

Then I tried to reference it with the event based rule set on the form submit button click. The rule definitely worked until I called this Data Element. The rule stopped working.

As far as I understand this code has to be set on the page with form to be able to capture original values and it should be active when the form is updated.

Is it possible to this via DTM? If yes, how to? Or may be somebody did it in the different way?

Comment: I like three returns at the end of the function :)

Comment: I am not a developer :)